# NSOutputStream stop working since iOS 8.3 update

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Why in the following code `class Test` doesn't receive stream events:

```
class Test
    : NSObject
    , NSStreamDelegate
{
    // NSStreamDelegate
    func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
        // this was never called
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let filePath = /*[some valid file path]*/
        if let stream = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: filePath, append: false) {
            stream.delegate = self
            stream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode) // I've also tried replacing currentRunLoop with mainRunLoop just in case the result was the same
            stream.open()
            _stream = stream

            println("Stream opened \(_stream!.hasSpaceAvailable) \(_stream!.streamStatus.rawValue) \(_stream!.streamError)") // here hasSpaceAvailable is true, stream status is opened and error is nil
        }

    }

    deinit {
        _stream!.close()
    }

    func write() {
        if (_stream!.hasSpaceAvailable) {
            let data = NSMutableData(length: 10000)
            _stream!.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data!.bytes), maxLength: data!.length)
        }
    }

    var _stream: NSOutputStream?
}
```

The class is not destructed (I have it as ViewController member). Am I doing something wrong? I can't find a problem in the code and I can't find anything related to my problem in the iOS 8.3, XCode 6.3 release notes. I didn't try it on Objective-C but most probably there will be the same problem.

Help is always highly appreciated!

Comment: Suggest you write in Obj-C , verify if theres an issue and send a bug report to bugreport.apple.com if there is.  8.3 is a very beta release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem, I had make the class private, and I guess because I'm setting as a delegate to the stream, calling functionality cannot see it and just doesn't call it.

Comment: Thank you! I had the exact same problem. Worked in XCode 6.2 then suddenly stopped working in 6.3.